# Facebook-like invitation page for my categorization service

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, user-interface

i am working on a categorization service. I want the experience to behave similarly to Facebook's invite/tagging function

Does anyone have any experience implementing this? This includes:

- autocompleting based on list below
- if auto-complete does not turn up anything, give chance to do something else with that data

Would be super happy to hear any experiences, plugins that might be useful in helping me build this out

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a Quick Google reveals a lot of Informations

http://www.jquery.wisdomplug.com/jquery-plugins/facebook-jquery-plugins/23-best-jquery-facebook-style-plugins/

http://www.emposha.com/javascript/jquerymultiselect.html

http://www.prodevtips.com/2009/10/11/facebook-style-photo-tagging-with-jquery-ajax-and-joomla/

http://www.prodevtips.com/2009/10/11/facebook-style-photo-tagging-with-jquery-ajax-and-joomla/